# Differential equations system's solutions differ when one of the constant is 0

Tags: differential-equations, system, differentials, system-variables

I am solving the following system of equations with Mathematica.
$u'=-k_{1}ux+k_{2}x^2, x'=k_{1}ux-k_{2}x^2$
and I obtain the solution for x:
$x(t)=\frac{e^{k_{1}C_{1}(t+C_{2})}k_{1}C_{1}}{-1+e^{k_{1}C_{1}(t+C_{2})}(k_{1}+k_{2})}$.
When I solve the system when $k_{1}=0$ I obtain the solution for x:
$x(t)=\frac{x_{0}}{k_{2}tx_{0}+1}$ but if I substute $k_{1}=0$ in the first solution, I obtain $x=0$.

I could not understand why.
Could you please help?

Comment: That is really a mathematics question, but the simple answer is that by setting $k_1=0$, you are changing the form of the differential equation by eliminating a term containing the independent variable, which also changes the form of the solution.

Comment: When posting a question you should include the code that you used so that others can reproduce your results. Your solutions include an `x0` which is not included in your equations.

Comment: Well, x0=x(0) simply.